# How to enable auto increment primary key for Oracle database in PowerDesigner 16.6?

Tags: oracle, data-modeling, powerdesigner

I am new to SAP PowerDesigner I am trying to created tables and link them together to get the DB model and I am having difficulties on enabling Auto increment for the primary Key column of tables. Can someone please guide me

I have looked online and there was mentioning of check marking something called as Identity. But I do not see that option on Column properties.[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqA5U.jpg)

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXbnC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Oracle are you using?

Oracle 12+ supports identity columns. In PowerDesigner, the `Identity`option is available in the `Oracle` tab on the Column, when the DBMS for the Physical Data Model is ORACLE Version 12c.

[image: column property sheet]

```
create table CONTACTS (
   ID                   int                 
      generated always as identity ( start with 1 nocycle noorder)  not null,
   NAME                 varchar(100)          not null,
   constraint PK_CONTACTS primary key (ID)
);
```

For previous versions of Oracle, the autoincrement was implemented with sequence, and triggers. [See this page of PowerDesigner online documentation](http://infocenter-archive.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.docs_12.0.0/html/daug/daugp75.htm) for example.

Comment: I was looking at 11g and when I changed it to 12 it worked. Thank you.